# How to work with UIPanGestureRecognizer with ScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am working on an iPhone app that needs the animation like the iPhone Springboard that is a `UIScrollView` with a `UIPageControl`. On a long press of an icon it should animate like on the Springboard. The main point is, the icons should be able to be moved to any place while the others adjust automatically.  Has any one tried it?  I have been able to do the moving of the icons with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and move the icons, but I'm not able to adjust the others.

Could anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you figured this out?